# How can I resolve "The argument type '

Tags: flutter, dart, message, getter

The getter 'message' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'message', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'message'.

[image: image of the problem]

I searched and didn't find any solution
And I want to help someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it's firebase auth. Replace your catch(e) with this
on FirebaseException catch (e)

https://prnt.sc/Nx2K2WpsEOI5

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the error object `e` with another...
e doesn't have a defined `message` attribute hence the error...

use `toString()` or interpolate like `'$e'` to get the value of exception caught.

Also, please copy paste your code to enhance readability in the future.
Hope it helps!

Comment: You can use formatting to make your answer easier to read, for example, by using backticks (\`) around inline code pieces like: `toString()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more.

Comment: yes was wondering how to do that ! Thanks! @AgainPsychoX